# Adding HTML/CSS Drop Down List To Navigation

Tags: html, css

I have started to develop a website: www.bossfakeid.co.uk - In the navbar where it says products, I need it to have this dropdown menu implemented: http://codepen.io/williamjamesclark/pen/HynGo - All I need is the drop down menu and the caret. Nothing else, I can change the colors. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not explain, what YOU tried so far. (or it shows that haven't tried anything yet...) No one will code this for you over here.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a `<ul>` inside the `<li>` you want to have a submenu.

```
<li>
      <a href="#" >Products<span style="color:#1D8A4C">▼</span></a>
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="">Submenu item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu item</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Submenu item</a></li>
      </ul>
</li>
```

Then, the following css is needed to style it correctly:

```
.submenu {
  position: absolute; /*1*/
  border-top: 15px solid transparent; /*2*/
  left: -9999px /*3*/
}

 li:hover > .submenu {
  left: -50px;
}



.submenu:before {
 content: ""; 
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1; /* bring in front of border */
 margin-top: 5px; /*1*/
 left: -9999px; /*2*/
 top: -15px;
 /* borders for up arrow */
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #34495e;
}

.submenu > li:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0; /*1*/
}

/*
  1. bottom rounded edges on submenu
*/
.submenu > li:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px; /*1*/
}

.submenu a {
  font-size: 90%; /*1*/
  margin: 3px; /*2*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background ease .3s; /*3*/
}

/* 
  submenu hover styles
*/
.submenu a:hover {
  background: #2AC56C;
}
.submenu li {
  background:#3B3B3B;
}
#menu .active a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #2AC56C;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.submenu:before {
 content: ""; 
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1; /* bring in front of border */
 margin-top: 5px; /*1*/
 left: 100px; /*2*/
 top: -15px;
 /* borders for up arrow */
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 10px solid #3B3B3B;
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle with the proper coding and example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/dLduK/2/)
You will want to study up on your CSS for menu building:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu
[Google before you ask](https://www.google.com/search?q=+CSS+menu+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb)

Comment: @user3786334 Here is how you fix your problem from your other question http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/S6JYm/show/ and here is the coding needed http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/S6JYm/ copy the css, and replace your css with it.

Comment: Your problem was you had overriding styles in your menu and overflow:hidden; was applied to your header.